# Fetch a collection in Criteria API multiselect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have those entities

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> children;

    @OneToOne
    private Foo foo;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // ....
}
```

And I want to select them into view like that. Please notice that in real example I have much more joins and much more fields like from entity Foo

```
public class ParentView {

      private Long parentId;
      
      private Long fooId;

      private List<Child> children

}
```

I'm trying to do that with this Criteria API code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ParentView> query = cb.createQuery(ParentView.class);
Root<Parent> parentRoot = query.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Foo> fooJoin = parentRoot.join("children", JoinType.LEFT);
parentRoot.fetch("children")

query.multiselect(
        parentRoot.get("id"),
        fooJoin.get("id"),
        parentRoot.get("children")
);
```

But getting error

```
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

If I include root into multiselect call as a first parameter (as an owner of fetched join) I'm getting the same error.

I've tried some workarounds with subquery or simple join without fetch but they all results in some error. Is there a way to map query results to the collection field of view in Hibernate or some workaround to do that?

Comment: This query has too many joins: parent, you've got a join to children 'fooJoin', a fetch join to children, and then yet another one in the select with parentRoot.get("children"). Each would add entirely independent joins when you likely only want one - but fetch join doesn't make sense if you aren't actually fetching the parent. Why not just fetch the parent entity instance directly and force JPA to fetch the children for you in the same query? You would be able to get the parent id and child id direct from the instances.

Comment: Strange to here that two joins are too many. If possible could you write some code sample of how it could be solved.

Comment: @Chris about joins I need them to generate a representation of the data I need. Probably the better solution here is to extract entities by several queries and after that join them with some object manipulation. Not sure which way is the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA lets you fetch entities, but when fetching data, you get the data as it is returned from the database - row by row. This means you cannot get parsed collections of children like what gets built into the Parent entity.

To fetch the data from the original question (ids, and child instance)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cquery = cb.createQuery();
Root<Parent> parentRoot = query.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Foo> fooJoin = parentRoot.join("foo", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<Parent, Child> childJoin = parentRoot.join("children", JoinType.LEFT);

cquery.multiselect(
        parentRoot.get("id"),
        fooJoin.get("id"),
        childJoin
);
..
cquery.orderBy(parentRoot.get("id"));
Query query = em.createQuery(cquery);
List<Object[]> scalarResults = query.getResultList();

Map<Long,ParentView> map = new HashMap<Long,ParentView>();
for (Object[] row : scalarResults) {
  if (!map.contains(row[0]) {
    map.put(row[0], new ParentView(row[0], row[1], row[2]);
  } else {
    map.get(row[0]).addChild(row[2]);
  }
}
return map.values();
```